# WMI sometimes takes indefinite periods on local machine

Tags: c#, wmi, visual-studio-2013

I use a WMI in a couple of places in a few applications but sometimes the application gets stuck at the WMI get method. When this happens nothing seems to be able to recover it except for a machine restart. Stopping debugging / ending process in task manager and then restarting the application causes it to hang at the same point. Once WMI has started hanging no application is able to get any results. Waiting for WMI to recover takes an indefinite amount of time and never seems to amount to any following improvements until a machine restart.

A couple of my code extracts:

GetInstances() is where this code hangs.

```
public static ChassisTypes GetCurrentChassisType()
{
    ManagementClass systemEnclosures = new ManagementClass("Win32_SystemEnclosure");
    ManagementObjectCollection results = systemEnclosures.GetInstances();
    foreach (ManagementObject obj in results)
    {
        foreach (int i in (UInt16[])(obj["ChassisTypes"]))
        {
            if (i > 0 && i < 25)
            {
                return (ChassisTypes)i;
            }
        }
    }
    return ChassisTypes.Unknown;
}
```

Get() is where this code hangs.

```
public static string GetOSInfo()
{
    System.Management.ManagementObjectSearcher objMOS = new ManagementObjectSearcher("SELECT * FROM  Win32_OperatingSystem");
    try
    {
        foreach (ManagementObject objManagement in objMOS.Get())
        {
            // Do stuff to build OS version string
        }
    }
    catch (Exception)
    {
    }
    return OSName;
}
```

How do I stop the calls from hanging and freezing the rest of WMI?

Comment: Does it hang also when you fire the same query from powershell command line ?

Comment: That makes for an interesting development; I can call any other object from powershell without any problems but if I call the same one as my app (`Get-WmiObject -Class “Win32_OperatingSystem"`) powershell doesn't return a value and my app stops hanging and passes this point. Another call from my app (whether same class or not) returns a value to powershell but the app hangs again. And so the cycle continues. If I run two instances of my app though both of them hang rather than one letting the other continue.

Comment: *On second check, if I run two instances of my app one lets the other continue as well.

Comment: We can have one way of checking this, can you fire your WMI calls in a separate thread that can be killed if a `TimeOut` occurs ? Because the WMI calls do get hanged sometimes if not provided with correct values, but what I am more concerned about is that we determine that whether they are really taking that long , or is something else wrong.

Answer (score 0):

You have to be sure you're using right `WMI` instructions. Try debugging you app with **breakpoints** to find out what may be wrong.

> Nice [WMI usage sample (Task Manager)](http://wantcode.tk/%D0%B4%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%BF%D0%B5%D1%82%D1%87%D0%B5%D1%80-%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%B4%D0%B0%D1%87-%D0%BD%D0%B0-wpf-%D1%81-%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%B7%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5%D0%BC-wmi/) (sources available for **download**) on my blog (written in Russian) may help you

Comment: I believe the commands are correct as they mostly return the expected values quickly.

Comment: Maybe you call them too frequent, or forget to dispose something?

Comment: Only call the WMI at startup which shouldn't be to frequent but I didn't explicitly dispose the management objects. When I added Dispose calls in it didn't seem to make a difference. Have restarted the machine now and it's working again (as orginally stated) and haven't managed yet to get back into the faulty state. Will report back in a couple of days to say if it develops the fault again or or not.